# Set a downloaded image to Imageview from url - IoS

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurl, nsimage

I have an url, clicking which it downloads the image. I want to set the image to the imageview. Currently have tried this but the image does not load. Can anyone suggest where i am going wrong.

Thanks in advance!

```
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3695/9258420948_566a38bfdb_q_d.jpg"];
pic1.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:[CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:url1]];
```

Comment: `imageWithContentsOfURL` may return nil if an error occurs. Check that the CIImage object is not ni.

Comment: The url i have shared downloads the image on clicking it rather than opening in the browser, can it be the reason why i am not able to place it in the imageview?

Comment: try a different URL then

Answer (score 1):

You want to use AFNetworking's category on UIImageView:

```
[myImageView setImageWithURLRequest:urlRequest placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    myImageView.image = image;
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Request failed with error: %@", error);
}];
```

It is worth working with AFNetworking just for this call. (AFNetworking also gives you a placeholder image, and it also caches network images so subsequent calls use the cache giving you a quick response.)

Comment: The url i have shared downloads the image on clicking it rather than opening in the browser, can it be the reason why i am not able to place it in the imageview?